# MSSQL не понимает кириллицу

Tags: sql-server

Проблема следующая. Создаю базу

```
create database MyTestDB on primary
(name = MyTestDB, filename = 'd:\MyTestDB.mdf',
size = 12MB,
maxsize = 20MB,
filegrowth = 2MB )
LOG ON
(name = MyTestDB_Log, filename = 'd:\\MyTestDB_Log.ldf',
size = 2MB,
maxsize = 12MB,
filegrowth = 1MB)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```

Затем создаю табличку

```
CREATE TABLE Students(
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Students PRIMARY KEY,
  Name nvarchar(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Ну и собственно заполняю её (текстовые поля - кириллицой). Как итог, всё то что на кириллице в таком виде `?????`
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема ? Где-то с кодировкой накосячил? Да вроде универсальная.

Comment: COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI

Comment: Именно с такой кодировкой и создаю.

Comment: Latin1_General = 1252

Comment: @Mirdin nvarchar же, причем тут collate

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков как именно заполняете и как именно выбираете данные? Может просто при заполнении строки как `'строка'` вместо `N'строка'` задали?

Comment: INSERT Students(Name) Values
('Иванов') и т.д. - заполняю.
select * from students - выбираю

Comment: напишите `N'Иванов'` - сейчас оформлю как ответ

Comment: Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции "N". При - INSERT Students(Name) Values
N('Иванов')

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков `(N'Иванов')` же :)

Comment: Работает... а в чем проблема ? На другом ПК ровной такой же код работал без N

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков скорее всего другой collation был у базы

Comment: Но как другой если я намерено создаю с COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI; ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Строковые литералы Unicode - nvarchar - нужно задавать с префиксом N:

```
N'Иванов'
```

[Без префикса строка будет преобразована с использованием кодовой страницы базы](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), и часть символов скорее всего будет испорчена:

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

Answer (score 1):

не правильный `COLLATE` выбираешь при создании БД, вместо `Latin1_General_CI_AI` выбери `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`